# function keep returning 0 and parameters not read

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

float sinfa(num1, num2)
{
    float fc;
    float powers;
    if(num1 == ""){
    powers = pow(num2,4);
    }else{
    powers = pow(num1,4);
    }
    fc = sin(num1-powers+1);
    return (fc);
}

float tp(fa,fb,num1,num2)
{
    float p;
    float fm2 = fa*num2;
    float fm1 = fb*num1;
    p = (fm2-fm1)/(fa-fb);
    printf("%f",fa);
    return (p);
}

float main()
{
double num1;
double num2;
float fa;
float fb;
float p1;

    clrscr();
    printf("Enter number 1: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    getch();
    printf("Enter number 2: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    getch();
    clrscr();
    fa = sinfa(num1);
    printf("%f \n",fa);
    getch();
    fb = sinfa(num2);
    printf("%f",fb);
    getch();
    clrscr();
    p1 = tp(fa,fb,num1,num2);
    printf("%f",p1);
    getch();

}
```

i kept getting 0 from the function tp, and the parameters does not enter when i sent them any ideas why? since for sinfa the parameters are sent and it returns a value

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give types to the function parameters.

```
float tp(float fa,float fb,int num1,int num2)
```

Otherwise they are considered `int` and that leads to confusing effects.

Similarly you should fix

```
float sinfa(int num1, int num2)
```

This wont cause a problem, but it is always good to be explicit about what you mean.

Comment: even though they are already declared? but how come for sinfa it was working?

Comment: i see thank you, but i still get 0 returned. though the paremeters are sent.

Comment: @magicianIam: the parameter names are independent of the variable names you have declared.  You might want to consider using a compiler (or compiler options) that will generate warnings for this kind of thing. Using `conio.h` leads me to believe you're using something like an old MS-DOS based compiler. There are much better compilers available today for free.

Comment: @MichaelBurr this was the only one i found when i googled turbo c. it would be great if you can lead me to some of those new compilers. thank you :)

Comment: @magicianIam: sure thing - nuwen MinGW: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html  TDM MinGW:  http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/  MS VC++ 2012 Express: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop

Comment: @MichaelBurr which one would you recommend?

Comment: @magicianIam: VC++ Express has the whole IDE, the MinGW downloads are command line compilers only (which you might actually prefer - it's not hard to integrate them into most programming editors).  I haven't actually tried the 2012 version of VC++ Express - I'm assuming that it's much like the 2010 version (which is still available as well).

Answer (score 3):

> always keep one thing in mind, make the habit of mentioning data type
>   of variables at the time of function declaration & function
>   defination. here you have not mentioned type that means it is
>   considering it as default dat typa of `int`.

```
float tp(fa,fb,num1,num2)
         ^^missing data type at all parameter, mention data type
```